# Cloning entity in playframework

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have problem with cloning entity in my application created with play framework 2.1.
When I'm runing method below I get RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction.

My question is: What is a proper way to clone entity using jpa in playframework?

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public static Result edit(final Long id) {
    final Client client = Client.findById(id);
    if (client == null) {
        return notFound(String.format("Client %s does not exist.", id));
    }
    if(client.address.id == client.corrAddress.id){
        client.corrAddress = client.address.clone();
    }
    Form<Client> filledForm = CLIENT_FORM.fill(client);

    return ok(form.render(filledForm, "Edycja danych klienta"));
}
```

Address clone method:

```
public Address clone(){
    return new Address(this.street, this.postCode, this.city);
}
```

---

UPDATE:

I made some changes in code. I don't use method clone now, as @Christopher Hunt suggested.
I also got another error.

I made method cascade in Client class:

```
public void cascade(){
    if(address.equals(corrAddress)){
        if(address.id != null && corrAddress.id != null 
                && address.id.equals(corrAddress.id)){
            address.client = this;
            address.corrClient = this;
            address.saveOrUpdate();
            corrAddress = null;
        } else {
            address.client = this;
            address.corrClient = this;
            address.saveOrUpdate();
            corrAddress = null;
        }
    } else {
        if(address.id != null && corrAddress.id != null 
                && address.id.equals(corrAddress.id)){
            System.out.println("TEST");
            address.client = this;
            address.corrClient = null;
            address.saveOrUpdate();

            String street = this.corrAddress.street;
            String postCode = this.corrAddress.postCode;
            String city = this.corrAddress.city;

            corrAddress = null;

                    /** CODE BELOW CAUSES ERROR: **/

            corrAddress = new Address(street, postCode, city);
            corrAddress.client = null;
            corrAddress.corrClient = this;
            corrAddress.saveOrUpdate();

                    /** CODE ABOVE CAUSES ERROR: **/

        } else {
            address.client = this;
            address.saveOrUpdate();
            corrAddress.corrClient = this;
            corrAddress.saveOrUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

definition of address references in Client class:

```
@Valid
@OneToOne(mappedBy="client", orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Address address;

@Valid
@OneToOne(mappedBy="corrClient", orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Address corrAddress;
```

Now I'm getting error:

> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2, for class:
>   models.Address]]  at
>   play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]    at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]     at
>   play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]     at
>   play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0] javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given
>   identifier was found: 2, for class: models.Address    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1360)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1294)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:877)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]    at
>   models.clients.Client.update(Client.java:58) ~[na:na]     at
>   models.clients.Client.saveOrUpdate(Client.java:110) ~[na:na] Caused
>   by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given
>   identifier was found: 2, for class: models.Address    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:104)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:161)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2209)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:661)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:441)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:298)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]

Important is that I don't want to operate with 2 element list. I want 2 fileds (address, corrAddress) in my Client class.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, but I wonder if an exception is being thrown from within your code block...

Also consider using a copy constructor instead of using the clone method: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Comment: I updated question with more info.